# Sendind files to web servicce : HTTP Error 415 Unsupported media type

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller, http-status-code-415

I try from my rest client to send files to my web service but i keep getting 415 when i'm sure of the media type i'm sending.

I'm using spring MVC :

Here code of the rest client :

```
public Response uploadFile(FormDataMultiPart multipart, ...) {
    WebTarget target = client.target(uri);
    Response response = target.
            path(*path*).
            request().
            header("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data").
            post(Entity.entity(multipart, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA), Response.class);
    return response;
}
```

And here how i use my function :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "*map path*", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView saveAttachedFiles(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile myFile, Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {
    try {
     File file = new File( myFile.getOriginalFilename());
     myFile.transferTo(file);
     FileDataBodyPart filePart = new FileDataBodyPart("file", file);
     FormDataContentDisposition contentDisposition = FormDataContentDisposition.name("file").fileName(file.getName()).build();
     filePart.setContentDisposition(contentDisposition);
     FormDataMultiPart formDataMultiPart = new FormDataMultiPart();
     formDataMultiPart.bodyPart(filePart);
     Response reponse = clientRest.uploadFile(formDataMultiPart, ...);
}
```

Here request header of my client (from logs)

```
31 > POST ***
31 > Content-Type: multipart/form-data
31 > Cookie: $Version=1;JSESSIONID=***
31 > Referer: ***
--Boundary_1_523348906_1460533877988
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Disposition: form-data; filename="Penguins.jpg"; name="file"
```

Here code of the web services

```
@POST
@Path("/file")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response uploadFile(
        @FormDataParam("file") InputStream fileInputStream,
        @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition contentDispositionHeader,
        @QueryParam("uuid") String uuid) {

    AttachedFileDto attachedFileDto;
    try {
           ** Processing the file **
        }
}
```

And the web service response header

```
31 < 415
31 < Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
31 < Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With,Cache-Control,Pragma
31 < Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE
31 < Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3333
31 < Connection: Keep-Alive
31 < Content-Length: 0
31 < Content-Type: application/json
31 < Date: Wed, 13 Apr 2016 07:51:16 GMT
31 < Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
31 < Server: Apache
```

Do you have any clue ?

Thanks =)

Comment: Have you tried adding correct `MediaType`? E.g.: `@RequestMapping(value = "*map path*" , method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution to my problem, i was confused between PathParam and QueryParam.

Service was like this :

```
    @FormDataParam("file") InputStream fileInputStream,
    @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition contentDispositionHeader,
    @QueryParam("uuid") String uuid)
```

And i was putting my uuid parameter in path function :

```
public Response uploadFile(FormDataMultiPart multipart, ...) {
    WebTarget target = client.target(uri);
    Response response = target.
            path(*path*?uuid=12315465).
            request().
            header("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data").
            post(Entity.entity(multipart, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA), Response.class);
    return response;
}
```

Added the queryParam function :

```
public Response uploadFile(FormDataMultiPart multipart, ...) {
    WebTarget target = client.target(uri);
    Response response = target.
            path(*path*).
            queryParam("uuid", uuid).
            request().
            post(Entity.entity(multipart, multipart.getMediaType()));
    return response;
}
```

And now it works =)